# How to output data from two SQL tables?

Tags: sql

I need to find clients whose personal account balance is more than 100. Output client_id,balance, find clients who have more than 3 sim cards. Output name, number of sim cards, find customers whose birthday is next month. Output name, birth_date. I do not understand how these tasks can be done, I have tried many options. I am very grateful for the help

[image]

Comment: You want it all different output or everything in one ?

Comment: Yeah, it is differnet output. I'm new to SQL, I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @DaminiSuthar, is it possible to do this in different outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select 
    c.*
from
    clients c
    left join accounts a on a.client_id = c.client_id
    left join 
        (select account_id, count(*) cnt from sim_cards group by account_id) s 
            on s.account_id = a.account_id
where
    s.cnt > 3
    and a.balance > 100
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot. Thank you for your responsiveness, have a nice day)

Comment: @AllOneNeon if my answer helped you, please upvote it and/or mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

And finding the customer whose birthday is in next month can be done in several ways. Here are two:

```
SELECT
*
FROM CLIENTS
WHERE MONTH(birth_date) == 11 -- here you have to specifiy the month by yourself
```

or

```
SELECT
*
FROM CLIENTS
WHERE MONTH(birth_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()))
```